# Dependencies issues while installing fglrx

Tags: drivers, ati

The screen display is too sharp/distorted, i am trying to install the official drivers in hope that will fix it...

```
  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fglrx : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-15
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```